# Clear search results on keyup

Tags: jquery, events, function

I have a script which allows to display bing search results: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9T7E/6/)

If you type a letter you will see the results for this letter. If you then do backspace and then type the same letter you will not get any results, so:

1. type letter = results
2. backspace = remove results
3. typing same (first) letter = **NO results**

This happens becouse I set a code to take clear the results if the val of input is empty like this:

```
$('#searchbox').live('keyup', function(){

var teq = $('#searchbox').val();

     doSearch(teq); 


    if (teq == '')
    {
        clearResults();
    }

});
```

So by clearing the results like this I'm actually causing a problem the same time becouse there are no results for the second time a same query is made. So my question is: How can I clear the results in a way that I would still be able to do the same query? Which means:

1. type letter = results
2. backspace = remove results
3. typing same (first) letter = **results**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in your code this comment:

```
// if our search is not blank AND is not what we last searched for
```

therefore I changed the statement

```
if ((search!='') && (search!=lastSearch))
```

to:

```
if ((search!=''))
```

You can see the result: http://jsfiddle.net/F9T7E/10/

Comment: Thanks:) (How did you spot that..?)